# No order in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
Select nametwo
from cities
inner join usuarios
where cities.nametwo=usuarios.jug1
   or cities.nametwo=usuarios.jug2
   or cities.nametwo=usuarios.jug3
```

and the data is

> jug1 = 2 jug2 = 1 jug3 = 4

then, the query order the data by ASC, and I want that order it by the order of the select.
is there a way for do this? thanks

Comment: "by the order of the select" --- what's that?

Comment: SQL doesn't guarantee an order unless you specify one. You need to add an `order by` clause, but 'the order of the select' is too nebulous a concept for me to offer any advice.

Comment: I want to order by "jug1" "jug2" "jug2".....
The order would be: 2,1,4

Comment: jug2 and jug2 are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you use `inner join`, use an `on` clause.  This is required in every database except MySQL and it just looks really awkward.  Here is an equivalent query:

```
Select c.nametwo
from cities c inner join
     usuarios u
     on c.nametwo in (u.jug1, u.jug2, u.jug3);
```

This formulation actually directly suggests the answer.  Use the `field()` function:

```
order by field(c.nametwo, u.jug1, u.jug2, u.jug3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are wanting to order by the `usuarios` table unless I am misunderstanding.

```
Select nametwo
from cities
inner join usuarios
where cities.nametwo=usuarios.jug1
or cities.nametwo=usuarios.jug2
or cities.nametwo=usuarios.jug3
order by usuarios
```